# pack_forget() not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

After creating a Label object in tkinter I tried to remove label using pack_forget attribute. But script not working. I am using python version 2.7.9 in raspbian.
Code is like:

```
visual = Tkinter.Tk()
sample = Label(visual, text="Hello python!")
sample.pack()
visual.update()
time.sleep(2)
sample.pack_forget()
visual.update()
```

Comment: Your code works fine, I believe you say it does not work regarding your whole application because `pack_forget() `does not really remove the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of    `pack_forget()` is render the widget on which it is applied to be invisible (like it is *falsely* removed). The proof is that if you add, after `visual.update()` this line `print(sample.winfo_exists())` it will print you 1, which thing means your label still exists in reality. So to effectively get rid of your label, you must use `sample.destroy()` instead. In this later case, the line `print(sample.winfo_exists())` will print 0 meaning your label called sample does not exist any more.