# Tkinter pack_forget() and destroy() don't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with these two functions that don't work as expected.
I want to use a selection form drop-down menù and based on the selection two different set of checkbox are displayed in the root window. To do so, I use this code:

```
    from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def evaluation(form):
    form.pack_forget()
    form.destroy()
    form=Frame(root)
    GotPlatform=platform.get()
    for elem in PlatformOption[GotPlatform]:
        OptionButtonSel[elem]=Checkbutton(form, text=elem)
        OptionButtonSel[elem].pack()
    form.pack(fill="both", expand = 1)  

PlatformOption={'Option1':["option1-1","option1-2"],'Option2':["option2-1","option2-2"]}
OptionButtonSel={}

root = tk.Tk()
f1=Frame(root)
menuBar = tk.Menu(root)
menu1 = tk.Menu(root)
submenu = tk.Menu(root)
platform = StringVar()
submenu.add_radiobutton(label="Option1", value="Option1", variable=platform,command=lambda:evaluation(f1))
submenu.add_radiobutton(label="Option2", value="Option2", variable=platform,command=lambda:evaluation(f1))
menuBar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=menu1)
menu1.add_cascade(label="Select option", menu=submenu)

root.config(menu=menuBar)
root.mainloop()
```

The code works but whenever I change the options fron drop-down menù, the checkboxes option are stacked and aren't overwritten as expected.

This puzzles me since I have used this other code and it works as expected:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu, Label



def show_frame1():
    forget_all()
    f1.pack(fill="both", expand = 1)  
    


def show_frame2():
    forget_all()
    f2.pack(fill="both", expand = 1)  
    


def forget_all():
    f1.pack_forget()
    f2.pack_forget()


root = Tk()
f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
Label(f1, text="MENU SELECTED 1").pack()
Label(f2, text="MENU SELECTED 2").pack()
menubar=Menu(root)
subMenu=Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label = 'MENU', menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label = 'SUBMENU1', command = show_frame1)
subMenu.add_command(label = 'SUBMENU2', command = show_frame2)
root.config(menu = menubar)


root.mainloop()
```

Aside from addind destroy(), the usage of frame and pack_forget() seems identical to me.

I use Python 3.10.1, IDE Spyder last version, Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you create a form that never appears on the screen. You create it, but never call `pack` on it. You then pass this form to the function every time the button is clicked. In other words, you keep passing the original form, not the new one that is recreated.

The best solution is for your main code to call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the form, and then in the function you can delete the children of the form without deleting the form itself.

So, add the following shortly after creating `f1`:

```
f1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Next, modify `evaluation` to destroy the children rather than the form itself:

```
def evaluation(form):
    for child in form.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()

    GotPlatform=platform.get()
    for elem in PlatformOption[GotPlatform]:
        OptionButtonSel[elem]=Checkbutton(form, text=elem)
        OptionButtonSel[elem].pack()
```

Comment: that worked like a charm, thank you very much. It wasn't really clear to me the mechanism behind the form, and to be honest it still isn't, even I fully catch your solution. How was I supposed to know that the a Frame cannot be destroyed if isn't displayed first? I assumed that the element Frame exist anyway, no matter if it's displayed or not (and thus could be deleted). Also it appears that only the widget within the Frame can me destroyed separately, while I assumed that destroying the whole frame would destroy all the widget inside it.

Comment: @Daniele: _"How was I supposed to know that the a Frame cannot be destroyed if isn't displayed first? "_ - I never said that. You can definitely destroy a widget without it being displayed. The problem is, you were destroying it but you couldn't _see_ that it was destroyed since it was never visible. The problem was that you weren't destroying the new forms that you were creating.

Comment: @Daniele: _"I assumed that destroying the whole frame would destroy all the widget inside it. "_ - yes, destroying a widget also destroys all of its children.

Answer (score 0):

It gives the effect that it doesn't work because the widget is invisible to the screen. This topic however is further explained below

[pack_forget() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155285/pack-forget-not-working)

Just to prove my theory I did some other research about the topic and
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-forget_pack-and-forget_grid-method-in-tkinter/
explains the concept of pack_forget() perfectly